# shared preference Boolean is always returning false

Tags: java, android

I am using shared preference. Why this method is always returning `false` ?(this code btw from this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)) when or how it should return true? I want to check if its true to enter another activity

```
 public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean("login", false);
    }
```

when I am creating a user , I am adding Boolean true

```
 public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        Toast.makeText(_context, "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("login1");
        editor.putBoolean("login", true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString("name", name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString("email", email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }
```

this method is to check the return islogin true or false in this case its always false, how to fix that to return it ?

```
/**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything\
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status


        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Register.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
else {
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, UserProfile.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Session manager class

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        Toast.makeText(_context, "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("login1");
        editor.putBoolean("login", true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString("name", name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString("email", email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything\
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
     //   editor.putBoolean("login", true);

        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Register.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
else {
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, UserProfile.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean("login", false);
    }
}
```

edit

when I removed the `editor` from the cursor and I add it here, it worked

```
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
    editor = pref.edit();

       editor.putBoolean("login", true);

    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        Toast.makeText(_context, " Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Register.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

}

but the weird when If I am addin here , its not working

```
public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    Toast.makeText(_context, "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("login1");
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
    // pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("login", true);
...
```

Comment: When you save you have **editor.putBoolean("login", true);** and when you read it you have **pref.getBoolean("login", false);**. My first though is how you initialize pref and editor. It is possible that you are saving and reading from different locations.

Comment: I am new to sharedpreference , I am using one class for shared preference and I am accessing it only. ill post the full code of the class `sessionmanagment` @Tequilaman

Comment: See my answer below. I have some conflicts on one app and now I am careful as to how I get my sharedpreferences. You can look at the source in debug mode if you put a break point where you are using pref or editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
```

try

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Here is my context (ctx) in the debugger.

[image]

So the following is how you can check the preference file to verify that it matches. I also wrote the code different in the third screen shot to demonstrate how a small difference can change the preference location.

In the first screen shot, notice the debugger showing the location of the preference file I am writing to.
[image]

Next, look at the location of the file I am reading from and how I initialized my pref variable. My saved preference is true, just as I saved it in the last screen.
[image]

Finally, I initialized my pref differently. See the difference? My boolean is now false(default) and the file location is different.
[image]

Now, maybe you are setting up your preferences the same every time. Check to be sure. I had this exact problem years ago and it drove me nuts till I realized I had different preference files being used. This is how I found the problem.

Finally, look at the different ways I tried to get my context. See how each one is different in the debugger? This is probably not your issue, but when you have weird disconnects going on, look twice at exactly how you hook everything up.
[image]

I hope this helps...

Comment: why should I remove the pref_name , and priavte mode ? 
 
it didnt work, I guess the problem it is not accessing the constructor.

Comment: You can verify for a certainty if the shared preference file matches by putting a breakpoint where you read a preference and write to the editor. The variables section of the debugger will have a value called mFile. They both must match exactly. If not, then you need to find what is causing the difference.

Comment: Hi man it seems the problem when i am creating a user , the editor not adding true. When i add pref.edit (true) before checklogin it workd .. check plz my edit above

Comment: It seems to me that you need to verify **context** and the **preference file** in a debugger to verify you don't have a conflict. The debugger will not lie.

Comment: hi how to verfiy it I have run the debugger but i couldnt know how

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where the editor are pref is doing something. Run the debug mode and when the exicution stops on that line, look at the  pref file path and your context. Context shouldn't be the problem, but look anyway. The pref and editor file path is very important. They must match.

Comment: @Moudiz - See my updated answer. Click the screenshots to see them in detail.... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the editor is connected to the SharedPreferences. I don't see something unusual but it would be safer to use prefs.edit()...commit();

Comment: how to make sure that its connected ?

Comment: please can you explain how to use the prefs.edit() I have also add my full class sessionmanager ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how you are retrieving the value. But while committing the value, are you writing to the same preference file that you are retrieving from ?

```
  SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefFIle.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("login", true);
  editor.commit();
```

Otherwise, it is quite simple as you know.

**EDIT**

You can try this preference helper file. Replace your with this and try. If you still see the issue, then it is something else but not in preferences.

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    public static final String PFO_SHARED_PREF_NAME = "prefs_file";

    public static final String PREF_PLUG_STATE = "plug_state";
    public static final String PREF_ICE_BUTTON_STATE = "ice_button_state";

    private final SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private final Context mContext;
    private static SharedPreferencesHelper instance = null;


    private SharedPreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PFO_SHARED_PREF_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static SharedPreferencesHelper getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SharedPreferencesHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public boolean getPlugState() {
        return mPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_PLUG_STATE, false);
    }

    public void storePlugState(boolean state) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_PLUG_STATE, state);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

You call like this, for ex:

```
boolean pullPlugState = mPref.getPlugState();
```

This is a singleton but you can change it once it starts working. Or else this is not a big object so it's perfectly fine with singleton.

Comment: in the main activity I am calling `SessionManager.checklogin()`, in the class `SessionManager` I declared the Sharedpreference `my pref` in the constructor, is it possbile when I am calling checklogin() its not entering the constructor ? ill add the full class

Comment: do not get editor in constructor. Instead, get the editor everytime you want any preferences. So, add SharedPreferences.Editor editor + pref.edit(); to your createLoginSession() method before you use editor. Remove the global editor variable. You should always get the latest Editor.

Comment: yes I am doing what you said and I am trying it give me one min please. thank you for you help

Comment: Check my edit .. it seems the edit.login (true) is not applying when creating a user . If i add the edit.loging true before the login fhecking its working. So the problem when i am creating a user the true is not being applied correctly dunno why

Comment: Create editor in every set and get methods. Remove the global edit variable. Did you do that?

Comment: Ok ill try it illl replace this one

Comment: I want to try your code but I noticed there is isnt a way to check if user is login